# Can not read from cloudformation stack when deploying to localstack

Tags: serverless-framework, localstack

I am trying to deploy my `serverless.yml` to localstack but I am facing some issues.
I have one `serverless.yml` which contains my infrastructure resources such a dynamoDB which I can successfully deploy to localstack.

Another `serverless.yml` references those resources in the `serverless.yml` like this:

```
MY_DYNAMODB_TABLE:
  !Select [1, !Split ['/', '${cf:${self:custom.infrastructureStack}.MyDynamoDBArn}']]
```

This works perfectly when I deploy everything to AWS, however when I try to deploy this to localstack I receive this error:

```
 - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.MY_DYNAMODB_TABLE.Fn::Select.1.Fn::Split.1": Value not found at "cf" source,
```

I am starting localstack via cli and deploying via `sls deploy --stage local`

When I look at the localstack cli output when deploying I can also not spot any error, the `AWS cloudformation.ListStackResources` returns `200` :

```
2023-04-26T12:38:39.871  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS cloudformation.ListStackResources => 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but I solved it by replacing

```
MY_DYNAMODB_TABLE:
  !Select [1, !Split ['/', '${cf:${self:custom.infrastructureStack}.MyDynamoDBArn}']]
```

with

```
MY_DYNAMODB_TABLE: 
  Fn::ImportValue: MyDynamoDBArn
```

which worked.